# IllegalStateException When Calling Subscriber onError() with OutOfMemoryException

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, rx-java

I have code that is designed to take a raw image, process it asynchronously, and let the user see their processed image. Sometimes, the image processing causes an OutOfMemory error, and I would then like to notify the user that their devices is out of memory.

I am getting a crash, however, when trying to catch the error and notify the subscriber. Furthermore, when I put breakpoints in the code, the OutOfMemory error is being caught, and the `subscriber.onError(e)` line is hit, but the `onPhotoProcessingError(e)` is never reached.

Here is where the subscription occurs:

```
imageDelegate.cropBitmap(rawPhoto, cameraManager.getPictureRotationDegrees(), cameraManager.getCurrentCameraId() == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(Bitmap bitmap)
                {
                    onPhotoProcessed(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e)
                {
                    onPhotoProcessingError(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted()
                {

                }
            });
```

Here is the code that catches the OutOfMemory error:

```
public Observable<Bitmap> cropBitmap(Bitmap rawPhoto, int rotation, boolean isFrontFacing)
{
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bitmap>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Bitmap> subscriber)
        {
            try
            {
                // rotates the photo so that it's portrait and cuts off the
                // bottom of the photo so that we have a square photo
                Bitmap rotatedSquarePhoto = PhotoUtils.rotateAndTruncateBottomOfPictureIntoSquare(rawPhoto, rotation);
                rawPhoto.recycle();

                // we want to mirror the image to match what the user saw when taking a selfie
                if (isFrontFacing)
                {
                    rotatedSquarePhoto = PhotoUtils.reflectAboutYAxis(rotatedSquarePhoto);
                }

                subscriber.onNext(rotatedSquarePhoto);
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
            {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the stack trace for the crash:

```
    04-06 16:40:55.303 22729-22729/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.emersonboyd, PID: 22729
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 921612 byte allocation with 861608 free bytes and 841KB until OOM
       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:787)
       at com.emersonboyd.util.PhotoUtils.rotateAndTruncateBottomOfPictureIntoSquare(PhotoUtils.java:225)
       at com.emersonboyd.delgate.ImageDelegate$2.call(ImageDelegate.java:124)
       at com.emersonboyd.delgate.ImageDelegate$2.call(ImageDelegate.java:116)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:169)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `OutOfMemoryError` is considered as *fatal error* by `RxJava`. Such errors are not "swallowed" internally and are not delivered to `onError` callbacks.

Here's a snippet from RxJava**1** source code. This method gets called at the beginning of every internal error handling block:

```
public static void throwIfFatal(Throwable t) {
    if (t instanceof OnErrorNotImplementedException) {
        throw (OnErrorNotImplementedException) t;
    } else if (t instanceof OnErrorFailedException) {
        throw (OnErrorFailedException) t;
    } else if (t instanceof OnCompletedFailedException) {
        throw (OnCompletedFailedException) t;
    }
    // values here derived from https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/748#issuecomment-32471495
    else if (t instanceof VirtualMachineError) {
        throw (VirtualMachineError) t;
    } else if (t instanceof ThreadDeath) {
        throw (ThreadDeath) t;
    } else if (t instanceof LinkageError) {
        throw (LinkageError) t;
    }
}
```

`OutOfMemoryError` is a descendant of `VirtualMachineError`.

More info:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/296
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/748

**Solution to your problem**: catch your `OutOfMemoryError` but push into stream any appropriate `Exception` subclass instead.

p.s. *tip*: for your case use `Observable.fromCallable` instead of `Observable.create`